# When we open an interactive python3 interpreter and run some commands, do we run the commands in some module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

When we open an interactive python3 interpreter and run some commands, do we run the commands in some module?  What is that module?

I ask this because `__name__` is `__main__` in such cases, and I think `__name__` is an attribute of some module which I don't know and am asking for. But `__dict__` and `__file__` as attributes of a module don't exist. The attributes which exist are:

```
>>> globals()
{'__package__': None, '__doc__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__name__': '__main__',   '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__spec__': None}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the interpreter session is the `__main__` module:

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr  5 2017, 20:56:42)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['__main__']
<module '__main__' (built-in)>
>>> sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__ is globals()
True
```

The `globals()` object **is** the module `__dict__` namespace. Don't confuse the contents of the namespace with the namespace itself (when you ask for the attributes of an instance, `__dict__` is not inside the instance `__dict__` attribute *either*).

The `__file__` attribute is *optional*; since you are not running from a file here, the attribute is not set:

```
>>> sys.modules['__main__'].__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'
```

Comment: You can also just `import __main__`.

Comment: @AlexHall: sure, but that'd just be an alternative way of getting the exact same object.

Comment: Thanks. Why not `__file__ : None` in the output of `globals()`? Why don't `__dict__` and `__file__` appear in the output of `globals()`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah but it seems like a less roundabout method than `sys.modules['__main__']`.

Comment: @Tim: Would that make any difference? The attribute is added only if the module has a file to be loaded from.

Comment: They why is `'__package__': None, '__doc__': None` in the output of `globals()`?

Comment: @Tim: `__file__` doesn't appear because that attribute is just not set. `__dict__` doesn't appear, because that'd be a circular reference. `globals()` *is that object*. Why would that object need to reference itself?

Comment: @Tim: I don't know. Because. Because it doesn't matter either way, and in some cases it is therefor set to `None` and in other cases just not set. `__doc__` is an attribute that all objects that can have a documentation string have and it is set to `None` there too, so that's consistent.

Comment: @Tim: if you ever find a reason that `__file__` should be set to `None` rather than omitted, do let the Python developers know and I'm sure they can add it. I don't see any reason for it to be set though.

Comment: (1) If `__file__` isn't set, then are `__package__` and `__doc__`  set? Why are they treated differently? (2) if it makes sense that `globals()` doesn't show `__dict__`, then why when I type `__dict__` directly in the interpreter, it also says `NameError: name '__dict__' is not defined`?

Comment: @Tim: again, `__dict__` is **not in the namespace**. It is the namespace itself. You can't reach it from within the namespace, that'd be like asking why there is no glass inside the fishbowl. `__dict__` is not a name in the current namespace, it is the container of the current namespace, and that's why the `NameError` is thrown.

Comment: @Tim: those different names are set by different parts. There is no central authority that takes care of all of those names. `__doc__` is set at compile time (on the code object). IIRC `__package__` is a standard attribute of a module object. `__file__` is set when you import a module from a file, and the interpreter 'module' was never loaded from a file.